# To use another class inside a new class, should I inherit?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

**Background:** I have a `class Button` that contains state data, textures and some member functions like `draw()`. Now I want to make new `class Buttons` that will contain a vector of Button object(s) (`vector<Button> ButtonList`), and member functions to maintain them and potentially trigger actions based on clicks. `Button` is in a separate header and cpp file. The `~Buttons` takes care of deleting the individual `Button` objects.

**Question:** Do I gain any advantage in inheriting the Button class, instead of just `#include Button` ? Or are there pitfalls I should be aware of.

I do intend to expand on the `Button` class at a later date.
I'm probably overthinking this a little, and I am fairly new to classes.

Example of include:

```
#include <vector>
#include "Button.h"

class Buttons
{
public:
    Buttons();
    ~Buttons();

    void addButton(int ID);
    void removeButton(int ID);
    void updateButtons();

private:
    std::vector<Button> buttonList;
};
```

Example of inherit:

```
#include <vector>
#include "Button.h"

class Buttons:Button
{
public:
    Buttons();
    ~Buttons();

    void addButton(int ID);
    void removeButton(int ID);
    void updateButtons();

private:
    std::vector<Button> buttonList;
};
```

Comment: `inheriting the Button class, instead of #include Button` I don't see how one is a replacement for, or even particularly related to, the other. In any case, I don't see the point of deriving `Buttons` from `Button`.

Comment: I meant, instead of just including >< oops. Edited.

Comment: Is a collection of buttons a button itself? Not really. So don't inherit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question: Do I gain any advantage in inheriting the Button class,
>   instead of just `#include Button` ?

This particular question does not make sense, because the issues are orthogonal. Both inheritance and composition with a `std::vector` require the full definition of `Button` and thus `#include "button.h"`.

> I'm probably overthinking this a little, and I am fairly new to classes.

When in doubt, **favour composition over inheritance**.

> ```
> #include <vector>
> #include "Button.h"
>
> class Buttons
> {
> public:
>     Buttons();
>     ~Buttons();
>
>     void addButton(int ID);
>     void removeButton(int ID);
>     void updateButtons();
>
> private:
>     std::vector<Button> buttonList;
> };
> ```

That's a very good solution. You cannot get much cleaner C++ than that.

> ```
> class Buttons:Button
> ```

This line, in contrast, does not make much sense. It uses **private inheritance**, which models composition, because the type is a `class`. I am quite sure that this is absolutely not your intention. Why would you add an extra `Button` if your class already contains a `std::vector<Button>`?

The line reads as *"A Buttons object **contains** one Button"*.

Public inheritance would make even less sense, of course:

```
class Buttons : public Button
```

This would read as *"A Buttons object **is** one Button"*.

> ```
> private:
>     std::vector<Button> buttonList;
> ```

So, combined with this line, the two inheritance versions above mean either *"A Buttons object **contains** one Button and also some more Buttons"* or *"A Buttons object **is** one Button and also contains some Buttons"*.

---

Bottom line: Use the inheritance-less version.

There is, however, one other sentence in your question which sounds a bit alarming:

> The `~Buttons` takes care of deleting the individual `Button` objects.

Yes, but only very indirectly, because the `std::vector` destructor does that automatically. In fact, in the code you have shown, you do not need to declare a destructor at all. If you do any extra work in the destructor, then chances are there is something wrong.

Comment: I was using `pop_back` to empty the vector. From what you are saying, I guess that's overkill ><. And thank you for a detalied breakdown!

Comment: @Mark: Yes, manually removing all elements before destruction is completely redundant. One of the reasons for using `std::vector` is precisely that you do *not* have to think about such things. You are welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

You should *not* make `Buttons` inherit `Button`, as there would be no meaning to use an object of type `Buttons` where an object of type `Button` is expected.

Inheritance is the strongest possible relation into two (or more) classes, it should not be used for simple code refactoring, still less to define a "collection of" relation.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up. Most of the examples i have read about classes and inheritance are _(neccesarily :-p )_ always inheriting. I was feeling I was doing something wrong by _**not**_ inheriting.

Comment: @Mark: C++ uses inheritance surprisingly sparingly. That's because it has many different programming paradigms built into the language. For example, all standard-library containers (like `std::vector`) are based on the idea of generic programming, implemented with templates. It's just very different from, say, Java, which naturally uses inheritance a lot more. C++, in contrast to other programming language, also has `private` and `protected` inheritance, which are semantically different from the "normal" `public` one. However, of those two, only `private` inheritance is *sometimes* useful.